# Are kCFNull and [NSNull null] Interchangeable

Tags: iphone, ios, null

It seems to be

```
if(myObj == (typeOfMyObj *) kCFNull){
 //myObj is null
}
```

and

```
if(myObj == (typeOfMyObj *) [NSNull null]){
 //myObj is null
}
```

produce the same result.

Is this always the case?  I'm developing an iOS 5 application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears none of Apple's docs state that `NSNull` and `CFNullRef` are toll-free-bridged, but it nevertheless seems that they are and have been since `CFNullRef` was introduced in Mac OS X 10.2. `NSNull` was available starting with Mac OS X 10.0. In the end, they are both really just sentinel values that serve as a distinguished NULL object.

There's probably a way for your code to avoid depending on `kCFNull == [NSNull null]`, but if you can't for some reason, then I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I just wanted to make sure one way wasn't preferred over the other (since kCFNull is only mentioned in Mac OS X documentation and not on the iOS side).

Comment: The thing is, it would be nice to be able to use `kCFNull` instead of `[NSNull null]` because the latter is a message call that needs to go through the message dispatch system and therefore is slow, whereas the former is a direct dereference.

Comment: If you're the only one introducing null values into a collection, then feel free to use exclusively `kCFNull`. It's only when you start trying to mix-and-match that you might wander into something questionable.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Jeremy,

If you wanted to be 100% safe, the best bet would be to check the class using isKindOfClass:

ie:

```
[object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
```

or

```
[object isEqual:[NSNull null]]
```

Then you're safe against any future changes, though it's super tedious and the slowest of all proposed approaches :P

It's not out of the question that one day

```
[[NSNull null] isEqual:(id)kCFNull] == YES
```

but

```
([NSNull null] == kCFNull) == NO
```

or even

```
([NSNull null] == [NSNull null]) == NO
```

Though these are the sorts of concerns that cause most Obj-C devs to spend more time jumping through hoops than writing code :P